# Poltergeist Error on first Capybara Test - Travis

Tags: phantomjs, capybara, travis-ci, poltergeist

My test suite is using Capybara for feature testing with PhantomJS as the driver for headless testing. We have gotten both up and working on Travis for our CI suite, but we're still getting failures as the suite runs (it works perfectly locally). Upon further examination I have realized that it is always the first feature test to run that is failing, every time, regardless of the order (our tests are executed in a randomized order). After it fails it gives this error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError:
   Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:52455/#/login' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status
   # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:351:in `command'
   # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:34:in `visit'
   # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/poltergeist-1.9.0/lib/capybara/poltergeist/driver.rb:95:in `visit'
   # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:233:in `visit'
   # /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
```

We are using version 1.9.0 for Poltergeist and 2.1.1 for PhantomJS. Every test that runs after this one work, even if they depend on this strategy to work (i.e. when testing authentication).

Has anybody encountered this issue / have any wisdom to share on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by adding the following bit of code to `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
end
```

Which is my understanding will set all Capybara tests to default to the javascript driver from initialization of the test suite  - which fixed the problem perfectly.

Comment: This should have zero effect on the problem you describe since it's already using the javascript_driver (as shown by the fact the error is coming from poltergeist).  Are you sure you didn't make other changes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your app is taking too long to startup, either investigate why your app is starting so slowly or increase the timeout setting for poltergeist in its driver registration.